# YouTube API getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl issue

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I would like to add a video to a playlist using GData. So I have no problem creating the playlist, but I can't manage to add a video to it. 
Here's what I do:

```
$playlist = $yt->newPlaylistListEntry();
$playlist->summary = $yt->newDescription()->setText("test");
$playlist->title = $yt->newTitle()->setText("test2");

$postLocation = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists';

$yt->insertEntry($playlist, $postLocation);

$feedUrl = $playlist->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl();

$videoEntryToAdd = $yt->getVideoEntry(..given id here..);
$newPlaylistListEntry = $yt->newPlaylistListEntry($videoEntryToAdd->getDOM());
$yt->insertEntry($newPlaylistListEntry, $feedUrl);
```

And I get the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:...\library\Zend\Gdata\YouTube\PlaylistListEntry.php on line 296

Which is caused by this code:

```
$feedUrl = $playlist->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl();
```

`var_dump` shows that the `$feed_url` is **NULL**. And it shows that `$playlist` is an object `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_PlaylistListEntry`, so I can't understand why it writes "property of non-object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is some kind of a bug in the API. So I've made a little workaround. It may seem ugly, but I had no other ideas.

```
function grab_dump($var)
{
    ob_start();
    var_dump($var);
    return ob_get_clean();
}

function getPlayListLink($playlist) {
    $test = grab_dump($playlist);
    $test = strstr($test, "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/");
    return strstr($test, "' countHint='0'", TRUE);
}

function addVideosToPlaylist($videos_arr, $playlistEntry, $yt) {
    $feedUrl = getPlayListLink($playlistEntry); 

    foreach($videos_arr as $video)
    {
        $videoEntryToAdd = $yt->getVideoEntry($video);
        $newPlaylistListEntry = $yt->newPlaylistListEntry($videoEntryToAdd->getDOM());
        $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylistListEntry, $feedUrl);
    }
}
```

And simply call it like that:

```
addVideosToPlaylist($vids_id, $playlist, $yt);
```